# Image Position in Attributed Text

Tags: swift, string, uiimage, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I've created an attributed text with some text and 2 images. I want to place one of the images at the front and the other at the end after the text. That is working good so far. My issue is that I want the second image at the end to be placed above the text like a quotation **"**. I am trying to position that image at the top, instead of having it at the bottom.

This is what I've tried:

```
let iconsSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: -5, width: 10, height: 10)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
let attachment  = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "quote1")?.maskWithColor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1))
attachment.bounds = iconsSize
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
if  let quotes = QuotesArray.instance.quotesArray.randomElement() {
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n \(quotes) "))
}
let attachment2 = NSTextAttachment()
attachment2.image = UIImage(named: "quote2")?.maskWithColor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1))
attachment2.bounds = iconsSize
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment2))
quotesLbl.attributedText = attributedString
```

Result:

**[image: Result]**

Comment: Are you saying that you want the second image to appear just after the word "itself"?

Comment: @maddy Yes, after the word and above it like a quotation

Comment: Did you try with different "y" until your find the correct one?

Comment: @Larme, sorry for the delayed response. Yes changing the "Y" value fixed the issue. That was my mistake, you should make your suggestion an answer so I can accept.